# Telerik Grid add, update and delete events not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

Telerik MVC grid column not identified until I add 
`@model IEnumerable<NTI.Data.EDC.LabUnit>` as first line of my view. However when I do add this line. 
Telerik MVC Grid loads with data and also shows ups all buttons. But Insert, Update and delete events not getting triggered. There is no Javascript error in the browser console window. And I also noticed there is no form action for Insert/Update/Delete buttons created by telerik. Please help.

My code ref: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-editing-ajax-editing.html

View

```
@(
Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add( c.ID))
    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
        //Ajax binding
        .Ajax()
        //Home.Index renders the grid initially
                .Select("LabUnits", "Lab")
        //Home.Insert inserts a new data record
                    .Insert("LabUnitsInsert", "Lab")
        //Home.Update updates an existing data record
                    .Update("LabUnitsUpdate", "Lab")
        //Home.Delete deletes an existing data record
                    .Delete("LabUnitsDelete", "Lab")
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ContactName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Country);
        columns.Bound(c => c.BirthDay);
        columns.Command(commands => commands
               .Edit()
               .Delete());
    })

)
```

Controller

```
public class LabController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult LabUnits()
    {
        IEnumerable<LabUnit> lbUnit = new LabUnitDB().SelectAll();

        return View(new GridModel(lbUnit));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult LabUnitsInsert()
    {
        //insert
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult LabUnitsUpdate(int id)
    {
        //update
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult LabUnitsDelete(string id){
        // Delete
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue. Had to replace

```
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
        //Ajax binding
        .Ajax()
```

with

```
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
        //Server binding
        .Server()
```

So its server binding and not Ajax.